# How to properly trigger multiple Raspberry Pi camera modules via GPIO?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, rpi.gpio, raspicam

I am working with three Raspberry Pi 3 B boards, which in turns have RPi camera modules V2 connected to each. I followed [this very detailed post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29438/problems-triggering-via-gpio) about triggering another Pi using GPIO pins and it works exactly as stated. I am able to trigger the camera on the second Pi by setting output pin 18 to High.

My pins are connected as follows:

- Pin 25 of Pi 1 is connected to the switch (5V)
- Pin 18 or Pi 1 is connected to pin 23 of itself and pin 23 of Pi2.
- Two Pi's have their grounds connected.

Configured as such, I have the camera module on Pi 2 take pictures, not two together. If the second Pi pin 23 is disconnected, Pi 1 takes pictures.

I tried to see whether voltages on pins 23 are not sufficient, but they are so unstable, I cannot measure them properly with a voltmeter.

Comment: Never connect a Pi GPIO to more than 3V3.